# web scraping from a single table, text is what I want but href links in table are from whole page. How to limit?

Tags: r

I'd like to extract the href links from exactly one of the tables at http://wfmu.org/playlists using the Rvest package.  I can grab a single table and confirm the table I have is the right one when I inspect with `html_table()`  BUT when I use `html_attr(name='href')` on the extracted table I get the links that are present on the ENTIRE page. I don't know where they are coming from. Why am I getting the entire page of links when I confirmed I am starting with one table on the page?  Thank you.

```
#test web scrape
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

rawDJURLs<- read_html(paste('http://wfmu.org/playlists',sep=""))
# get the urls of the each DJ's playlist feed
#table 9 is off sched. tables 2-8 are monday through sunday
t_monday<-rawDJURLs%>%html_node(xpath='//html//body//center[2]//table[1]//table[2]')
```

Confirm that the table we got is the monday morning line up

```
t_monday %>% html_table() %>% .[1,2]

[1] "The WoofMoo Morning Show\n- playlists and archives...

t_off<-rawDJURLs%>%html_node(xpath='//html//body//center[2]//table[1]//table[9]')
```

Confirm that the table we got is the off-schedule line up

```
t_off %>% html_table() %>% .[1,2]

[1] "100% Whatever\nwith Mary Wing\n- playlists and archives...
```

But when I extract the href links both contain the identical whole page of links!

```
t_monday%>% html_nodes(xpath='//a[contains(.,"Playlists")]')  %>% 
  html_attr(name="href") -> l_monday
t_off%>% html_nodes(xpath='//a[contains(.,"Playlists")]')  %>% 
  html_attr(name="href") -> l_off
l_off==l_monday

 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   
....    
[287] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is that XPATH you use to collect links inside the table (`'//a[contains(.,"Playlists")]'`) is absolute in respect to the whole HTML-page. I combined two XPATHs (for the table and to the links) and it worked:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

rawDJURLs<- read_html(paste('http://wfmu.org/playlists',sep=""))

l_off<-rawDJURLs %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//html//body//center[2]//table[1]//table[9]//a[contains(.,"Playlists")]') %>% 
  html_attr(name="href")

l_monday<-rawDJURLs %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//html//body//center[2]//table[1]//table[2]//a[contains(.,"Playlists")]') %>% 
  html_attr(name="href")

length(l_monday)
[1] 11
length(l_off)
[1] 236
```

Comment: It works. I don't see why concatenating two html_nodes() calls would do it, but it does.  Perhaps because the html_nodes() object is a pointer not a ,value?  t_off$doc and t_monday$doc are pointers to the same address.  Thanks!